# Caffeine tolerance

Tags: caffeine, drug-tolerance

I've noticed that the consumption of caffeine increases my productivity and improves my mood. That being said, I'm wary of acquiring a tolerance - I would like to take a low enough dose infrequently enough that I have an increase in energy and mood when using it, and return to my baseline when not using it. I would like to avoid developing a tolerance to the point that consuming Caffeine simply brings me back to what was previously my 'baseline'. I've done a fair amount of searching online, and was unable to find any reputable sources detailing information on caffeine tolerance.

On average, how much caffeine will a person have to consume, and how often, to develop a tolerance?

Comment: *The process of tolerance development is **reversible** (e.g., through a drug holiday[6]) and can involve both physiological factors and psychological factors.* Wikipedia. Are we surely talking about drug tolerance or rather drug addiction?

Comment: @Narusan I double-checked, and I am indeed talking about tolerance. I'll clarify my question via edit.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://health.stackexchange.com/a/16996/809

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 1-4 days for blood pressure tolerance, and 7-12 days for neurological tolerance (focus, energy)
[Scientific citations in the Duplicate question here](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/16996/809)